# Using MD5 as a versioning identifier

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema

I'm storing some JSON schemas in a DynamoDB table which is defined with keys:

- **type** - hash key
- **version** - uuid

The JSON schema will be stored in a `schema` attribute.

What I'm wondering is, would it be appropriate to use an MD5 or other hash of the schema blob as the `version` uuid, in contrast to a randomly generated uuid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat subjective as it depends on the semantics of the version attribute but if you would generally consider an identical schema to be the same version, even out of order, then yes. If not, then no.

What I mean by that is, consider this scenario:

1. "Schema A" is added to table, and it's version derived by hash is "1"
2. the item is modified and now has "Schema A1", with version derived by has "2"
3. the item is modified again, and it is made identical to "Schema A", so it's version becomes "1" again

Does this work for you? In some cases this is ok, in other cases it's not.

*Note: "Schema A" and "Schema A1", "1" and "2" are just simplifications without loss of generality.*

**edit**

As was pointed out in comments, another point to consider is whether white-space and ordering changes should be considered as different schema or the same.

Comment: Another important aspect to be considered is does position of data matter.
As it is mentioned it is json based schema so one time it could be {A:[1,2]} and second time it could be {A:[2,1]} though it may or may not represent same thing and md5 will be different